# How do I make Flask-Login pass the username as an argument into the load_user callback in the models instead of the id?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am trying to make my app load users from the User and Admin classes in the models. In the views for the login it goes into both tables to check if a user exists, and its doing this right. The problem is, after is finds a user in either one of the tables, it incorrectly, loads information from the Admin model. This is because the load_user callback:

```
# Set up user_loader
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Admin.query.get(int(user_id)) or User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

Is receiving the id of the matched account object as an argument. This presents a problem as the id's are primary keys so there is no uniqueness so two users will have the same id as these are implemented in incremental order. So if I login with a user of id 1, the load user callback then looks for a user with id 1, starting with Admin table since it is the one that is defined first. The first admin also has an id of 1 so then it grabs that user from the Admin model instead of the User model. How can I change the load_user callback to receive the username of the user instead of the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 4 methods **required** on your Flask-Login user classes

> is_authenticated - This property should return True if the user is
> authenticated, i.e. they have provided valid credentials. (Only
> authenticated users will fulfill the criteria of login_required.)
>
> is_active - This property should return True if this is an active user -
> in addition to being authenticated, they also have activated their
> account, not been suspended, or any condition your application has for
> rejecting an account. Inactive accounts may not log in (without being
> forced of course).
>
> is_anonymous - This property should return True if
> this is an anonymous user. (Actual users should return False instead.)
>
> get_id() - This method must return a unicode that uniquely identifies
> this user, and can be used to load the user from the user_loader
> callback. Note that this must be a unicode - if the ID is natively an
> int or some other type, you will need to convert it to unicode.

just make `get_id` return the username instead of self.id ... and then change your `load_user` to look it up

Answer (score 0):

[image: alternative tokens]

https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Maybe you can use alternative token instead